# How to convert String to QR Code Image in Vaadin?

Tags: java, image, vaadin

I have a string like

```
String s = "123456789";
```

and i want an Vaadin Image with the QrCode generated from the String, to display it in the window. So i want something like:

```
public Image toQr(String s) {
    <...>
    return imageOfQr;
}
add(toQr("Hello World"));
```

How am I supposed to do this?
Can you please help me giving the full method to have the same input and output. Im not interested in any other outputs.

Comment: What part do you have a problem with?

Comment: I tried using addons like zXingVaadin or even zXing but none of them are working for me, i only get empty elements with the size of 0x0. I want a method that i can hand over the String and get the QR Code as Vaadin Image. So i need help at creating the full method.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: You need a two step process, a java library which generates the qr image, then you store it somewhere on the server and then add it a a normal dynamic resource/image to your vaadin page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example class how to do it in two different ways. I'd also check the [ZXingVaadin add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/zxingvaadin), that probably does something similar (I have never tried it).

```
package org.example.views;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.oned.EAN13Writer;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Image;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.AbstractStreamResource;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.StreamResource;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@Route
public class BarcodeView extends VerticalLayout {

    public BarcodeView() {
        String barcodeText = "123456789012";

        Image barcode = new Image();
        barcode.setSrc(asStreamResource(generateEAN13BarcodeImage(barcodeText)));
        add(barcode);

        // Barcode images are typically small
        // & no need for caching, using as data URL is fine as well
        Image asDataUrl = new Image();
        asDataUrl.setSrc(toDataUrl(generateEAN13BarcodeImage(barcodeText)));
        add(asDataUrl);


    }

    private AbstractStreamResource asStreamResource(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
        return new StreamResource("barcode.png", (output, session) -> {
            try {
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", output);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public static final int BARCODE_W = 300;
    public static final int BARCODE_H = 50;

    public static BufferedImage generateEAN13BarcodeImage(String barcodeText) {
        EAN13Writer barcodeWriter = new EAN13Writer();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = barcodeWriter.encode(barcodeText, BarcodeFormat.EAN_13, BARCODE_W, BARCODE_H);
        return MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);
    }

    public String toDataUrl(BufferedImage image) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
            return "data:image/png;base64," + jakarta.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(baos.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats the answer im looking for, thank you.